# Extend Volume with dr operator - Is this allowed?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have a question regarding the extension of functions with differential operators.

Is the following allowed (I need to derivate volume by $r$)?
$$
\dfrac{dV(r)}{dt} = \dfrac{dV(r)}{dr}\cdot\dfrac{dr}{dt} = \dfrac{d\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3\right)}{dr}\cdot\dfrac{dr}{dt} = 4\pi r^2 \cdot\dfrac{dr}{dt}
$$

Comment: The writing is a bit off (should say $\frac{d \left( \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 \right)}{dr} \frac{dr}{dt}$) but this is just the chain rule.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thank you

Comment: Yes, that's basically the chain rule, here applied to the composed function $V(r(t))$.